# fail to use Q_OBJECT Macro in CMake Project

Tags: c++, qt, cmake, qobject, qmetaobject

I am having trouble with the meta Object Compiler of Qt in my CMake Project. A shared lib I am building contains the following code and employs the pimpl idiom. After invoking CMake and upon compilation I get

> AUTOGEN: error: ~/tools/Project/gui/src/mainWindow.cpp: The 
>    file contains a Q_OBJECT macro, but does not include "mainWindow.moc" !
>    gui/CMakeFiles/gui_automoc.dir/build.make:57: recipe for target 'gui/CMakeFiles/gui_automoc' failed
>   make[2]: *** [gui/CMakeFiles/gui_automoc] Error 1
>   CMakeFiles/Makefile2:234: recipe for target 'gui/CMakeFiles/gui_automoc.dir/all' failed

I dont get what I am doing wrong or whats the correct way to incorporate src files with the Q_OBJECT Macro in my project. Please help =/

gui/include/gui/mainWindow.hpp

```
#include <QMainWindow>
#include <string>


class MainWindow : public QMainWindow {
  class MainWindowImpl;

 public:
  MainWindow(QWidget* parent = nullptr);

 private:
  MainWindowImpl* pimpl_;
};
```

gui/src/mainWindow.cpp

```
#include "gui/mainWindow.hpp"

class MainWindow::MainWindowImpl : public QWidget{
 Q_OBJECT
  public:
   explicit MainWindowImpl(MainWindow *parent);

  private:
   MainWindow &parent_;
};

MainWindow::MainWindowImpl::MainWindowImpl(MainWindow *parent)
    : QWidget{parent}, parent_(*parent) {}

MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) : QMainWindow{parent} {
    pimpl_ = new MainWindowImpl{this};
    setCentralWidget(pimpl_);
}
```

I compile the libray like so:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.5.1 FATAL_ERROR)
project(gui)

QT5_WRAP_CPP(MOC_Files
include/gui/mainWindow.hpp
)

add_library(${PROJECT_NAME}
  SHARED
   src/mainWindow.cpp
   ${MOC_Files}
)
add_library(gui::gui ALIAS ${PROJECT_NAME})

target_include_directories(${PROJECT_NAME} 
  PUBLIC 
   ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/include
)

set_target_properties(${PROJECT_NAME} PROPERTIES AUTOMOC TRUE)

target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME}
  PUBLIC
   Qt5::Widgets
   Qt5::Core
   Qt5::Xml
   Qt5::OpenGL
   Qt5::Gui
)

install(TARGETS ${PROJECT_NAME} DESTINATION lib)
```

Now I want to link this lib against my executable

apps/main.cpp

```
#include <QApplication>
#include "gui/mainWindow.hpp"

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {

QApplication app{argc, argv};

MainWindow gui{};
gui.show();

return app.exec();
}
```

with the following CMakelists.txt where I link against the gui lib

```
cmake_minimum_required (VERSION 3.5.1 FATAL_ERROR)
project (app)

add_executable(${PROJECT_NAME}
  main.cpp
)

target_include_directories(${PROJECT_NAME}
    PUBLIC ${PROJECT_BINARY_DIR}
)

target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME}
  PRIVATE
   gui::gui
   Qt5::Widgets
   Qt5::Core
   Qt5::Xml
   Qt5::OpenGL
   Qt5::Gui
 )

 install(TARGETS ${PROJECT_NAME}
         DESTINATION bin)
```

my top-level CMakeLists of the project looks like the following

```
cmake_minimum_required (VERSION 3.5.1 FATAL_ERROR)
project(project)

set(CMAKE_INSTALL_DIR ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/obj)
set(CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX  ${CMAKE_INSTALL_DIR})
# add our local path to the runtime path
SET(CMAKE_INSTALL_RPATH "$ORIGIN:${CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX}/lib")
# also add the link paths to the runtime paths
SET(CMAKE_INSTALL_RPATH_USE_LINK_PATH TRUE)

find_package(Qt5 COMPONENTS Core Widgets Xml OpenGL Gui REQUIRED)

## --> Build libraries and applications  <--
add_subdirectory(gui)
add_subdirectory(apps)
```

Comment: Have you tried to add line `#include "mainWindow.moc"` into source `gui/include/gui/mainWindow.cpp`, as the error message suggests?

Comment: I did and got ~/tools/Project/gui/src/mainWindow.cpp:74:26: fatal error: mainWindow.moc: No such file or directory
compilation terminated.
gui/CMakeFiles/gui.dir/build.make:62: recipe for target 'gui/CMakeFiles/gui.dir/src/mainWindow.cpp.o' failed
make[2]: *** [gui/CMakeFiles/gui.dir/src/mainWindow.cpp.o] Error 1

Comment: Did you try `#include "gui/mainWindow.moc"` in `mainWindow.cpp` as suggested [here](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.0/prop_tgt/AUTOMOC.html)?

Comment: I've personally found AUTOMOC to be finicky, and in the end decided to manually invoke moc with `qt5_wrap_cpp(MOC_OUT ${INPUT})`, and then pass `${MOC_OUT}` to the list of sources in my library or binary. You might want to try that

Comment: did that as well by including it like I did above, didnt help

Comment: @Tsyvarev Can you clarify why it is required?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

It is a typical confusion about compiling Qt application with CMake.
Basically there are two approaches to run `moc` preprocessor with CMake:

## 1. CMake's approach with [`AUTOMOC`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.0/prop_tgt/AUTOMOC.html) property.

It is very easy to use but has a couple of requirements which are mentioned in the documentation.

- Make sure the property `AUTOMOC` is enabled for the target.

  ```
  set_target_properties(${PROJECT_NAME} PROPERTIES AUTOMOC TRUE)
  ```
- If your `.cpp` file contains `Q_OBJECT` macro then you need to include the generated `.moc` file after the last qobject class (better at the end of the file). For this step you also need to enable `CMAKE_INCLUDE_CURRENT_DIR` but it is a general recommendation for any CMake+Qt build.
- If your header file contains `Q_OBJECT` make sure CMake knows about it. The easiest way is to pass along with the source files:

  ```
  add_library(${PROJECT_NAME}
    SHARED
     include/mainWindow.hpp
     src/mainWindow.cpp
  )
  ```
- And finally link all required Qt libraries.

  ```
  target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME}
    PUBLIC
     Qt5::Widgets
     Qt5::Core
  )
  ```

So to fix your code in CMake's way:

gui/src/mainWindow.cpp:

```
#include "gui/mainWindow.hpp"

class MainWindow::MainWindowImpl : public QWidget{
 Q_OBJECT
  public:
   explicit MainWindowImpl(MainWindow *parent);

  private:
   MainWindow &parent_;
};

MainWindow::MainWindowImpl::MainWindowImpl(MainWindow *parent)
    : QWidget{parent}, parent_(*parent) {}

MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) : QMainWindow{parent} {
    pimpl_ = new MainWindowImpl{this};
    setCentralWidget(pimpl_);
}

#include "mainWindow.moc"
```

gui/CMakeLists.txt:

```
project(gui)

set(CMAKE_INCLUDE_CURRENT_DIR YES)

add_library(${PROJECT_NAME}
  SHARED
  include/gui/mainWindow.hpp
  src/mainWindow.cpp
)
add_library(gui::gui ALIAS ${PROJECT_NAME})

target_include_directories(${PROJECT_NAME} PUBLIC ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/include)

set_target_properties(${PROJECT_NAME} PROPERTIES AUTOMOC TRUE)

target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME}
  PUBLIC
   Qt5::Widgets
   Qt5::Core
)
```

## 2. Qt approach with [`QT5_WRAP_CPP`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5.10/cmake-manual.html)

Here you simply need to "wrap" all your header files that have `Q_OBJECT` in them and add the result to the list of source files.

Or if you have a class in cpp file it gets tricky. The `Q_OBJECT` macro adds member functions to the class. The implementation of any class member function outside of the class body needs to know the class declaration. These implementations are inside the generated `.moc` file but they cannot see the declaration of the class. The easiest way to fix it would be to split your `.cpp` file into two:

gui/src/mainWindowImpl.hpp:

```
#pragma once
#include "gui/mainWindow.hpp"

class MainWindow::MainWindowImpl : public QWidget{
 Q_OBJECT
  public:
   explicit MainWindowImpl(MainWindow *parent);

  private:
   MainWindow &parent_;
};
```

gui/src/mainWindow.cpp:

```
#include "gui/mainWindow.hpp"
#include "mainWindowImpl.hpp"

MainWindow::MainWindowImpl::MainWindowImpl(MainWindow *parent)
    : QWidget{parent}, parent_(*parent) {}

MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) : QMainWindow{parent} {
    pimpl_ = new MainWindowImpl{this};
    setCentralWidget(pimpl_);
}
```

And include the additional header in the `QT5_WRAP_CPP`:

gui/CMakeLists.txt:

```
project(gui)

QT5_WRAP_CPP(MOC_Files
  include/mainWindow.hpp
  src/mainWindowImpl.hpp
)

add_library(${PROJECT_NAME}
  SHARED
   src/mainWindow.cpp
   ${MOC_Files}
)
add_library(gui::gui ALIAS ${PROJECT_NAME})

target_include_directories(${PROJECT_NAME} 
  PUBLIC 
   ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/include
)

target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME}
  PUBLIC
   Qt5::Widgets
   Qt5::Core
)
```

---

**Note!** Be careful with `moc` and classes that use complex syntax as there are [limitations](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/moc.html#nested-classes-cannot-have-signals-or-slots).